# Things to consider when hosting more than one websites on a server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web

I have two websites running on IIS 7. Both require SSL. Ports for the websites are http:8080/https:443 and http:8087/https:443  respectively. I've created self signed certificate and put them into the Trusted Root. Contents of the both websites are the same. Here are my questions:

1. Do I have to make some changes to the hosts file as well? If so, what changes exactly, both on
   server and clients
2. What do I have to type in the address bar in order to be able to open them? (Like 172.16.10.1/website1?) Do I have to specify the port numbers?

Comment: `http://172.16.10.1:8080` for website1 and `http://172.16.10.1:8087` for website2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For http traffic, you can have many websites which can differ by IP or Port or Host Headers or a combination.

So in your case it is simple. For website1, you have site binding on port 8080, so the url becomes `http://172.16.10.1:8080`. Ditto for website2: `http://172.16.10.1:8087` .

To make things simple, you can do a sitebinding on host header. So, bind the IP `172.16.10.1` with default port 80 to a host header say "www.website1.com" for the first website. Simlary for the other make the same combination bind to "www.website2.com". Now you don't need to specify port in the url. You can simply open both the websites by their respective names.

However, in case of https, it becomes a bit tricky. The certificates are installed on a per server basis. So, you have to specify different IP-Port combinations and host header binding won't work.

One option you have is to use a wildcard certificate which you can then secure-bind to each host-header.

The other option is to get a SAN Certificate (Subject Alternative Name Certificate). This will allow you to do a binding on different host headers with the same IP-port combination.

This excellent article on MSDN will help you understand it better: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

Regarding the first part of your question:

You don't need to do anything with the hosts file. If you have a proper third-party certificate, it only needs to be registered on the server. The Intermediate and Trusted roots are already available on the clients. So nothing to be done on the client-side. You can open up "options" in IE and then check "certificates" under the "content" tab to see that a list of publishers is already there.

However, if you are using a self-cert, then the client-part is tricky. Because, the clients will keep on getting the "certificate is invalid" warning every time. One way out of this is to manually install the certificate on each client. Another way is to deploy the certificates to all clients using group policy.